# Shortest path between two vertex in a complete graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I have a complete graph with N vertices and I need to find the shortest path from a given source to a given destination. All edges have initial cost A, then for K edges the cost will change to B. What is the best way to find the minimal cost between vertex 1 and vertex N [The algorithm finds the lowest cost (i.e. the shortest path) between vertex 1 and vertex N]? The input is N K A B and K edges (the edges with cost B).

where:

```
2 <= N <= 500000
0 <= K <= 500000
1 <= A, B <= 500000
```

I've tried with Dijkstra but take to much time ~ 2min, and i need something like 2sec.

Comment: As far as I know Dijkstra's one of the faster algorithms you can use, you might need to optimise or completely change the type of pathfinding.

Comment: @AnubianNoob That's true for general graphs, but there's a lot of structure here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the cost of the edge between `1` and `N` is `A`.

   1) if `A<B`, then the lowest cost will be `A`.

   2) if `A>B`, then use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find the fewest hops from `1` to `N` through only the edges with cost `B`. Assume that there are at lest`L` edges between `1` and `N`, then return `min(LB,A)`. It is typical `BFS` and the cost is `O(N+K)`.
2. If the edge between `1` and `N` is `B`.

   1) if 'A>B', then the answer is `B`.

   2) Find the fewest hops from `1` to `N` only using the edge with cost `A`. Let `S[h]` be the set of vertices can be reached by `h` hops and `S'` be the set have not reached yet, then it can be solved as follows.

   `min_dis() {
       S[0] = {1};
       int h = 0;
       S'={2,...,N};
       while (S[h] is not empty) {
         S[h+1] = {}; 
         for_each (v1 in S'){
           for (v2 in S[h]) {
             if (cost[v1][v2] == A) {
               S[h+1].insert(1);
               S'.remove(v1);
               if (v1 == N) return min((h+1)*A, B);
               break;
             }
           }
         }
         h++;
       }
       return B;
     }`

   We can proof that this algorithm is also `O(N+K)`, since each time we test`const[v1][v2]==A` is `true` , the size of `S'` will be decreased by `1` and there are at most `K` time when this test is `false` because there are at most `K` edge with cost `B`. So it guarantees to be finished with `O(N+K)`

In total, the algorithm is `O(N+K)`, which will guarantee the `2sec` time limit.

Comment: thank you a lot. And what is the best data structure to use in this case?

Comment: @JeanBubu I will revise my answer.

Comment: yeah, but in this case i will double number of edges. All neighbors will store v to beacause it's an undirected graph

Comment: I have revise my answer and it is quite different form the previous one. Maybe you need use set or list for S' and array for S[h]

Comment: Stiil don't work for big graphs. takes like 15sec or even more. Ex: work for [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5bt0pw5spfctx4/scrisori5.in) but fail for [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yt7frrzf4v9ecfg/scrisori36.in) or [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k28finjz1ut6p2w/scrisori27.in)

Comment: @JeanBubu Would you please give me the link to submit the solution? I want to implement this algorithm and have a try. Thx

Comment: @JeanBubu I have implemented this algorithm and it seems okay for all the 3 links. I can send you my code if necessary.

Comment: I am close to, I remove "S'.remove(v1)" from your code and now take like 3-4 sec for some big graphs but not all. Please, if you give me your code I would be very grateful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50846/discussion-between-notbad-and-jeanbubu)

Comment: https://code.stypi.com/lmynwxlr